# Encoding which differs from ASCII even for letters

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, ascii, codepages

Are there any character encodings out there which are reasonably common on consumer devices (as opposed to mainframes) and which map the letters `A-Za-z0-9` different to ASCII?

Currently I'm thinking about a Java application, so I wonder whether there are any chances that a casual user of some Java software in some country could end up with [`defaultCharset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset()) being reported in such a way that [`"AZaz09".getBytes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()) returns something different than [`"AZaz09".getBytes("UTF-8")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String)). I'm trying to work out whether I have to address certain compatibility issues which might result from a different behavior in this respect.

I know that historically, EBCDIC would be the prime example of an ASCII-incompatible encoding. But is it being used on any recent consumer devices, or just IBM mainframes and vintage computers? Does the legacy of EBCDIC live on in some country's common encodings?

I also know that UTF-16 is ASCII-incompatible, and that it's quite common to encode files that way on Windows. But as far as I can tell, that's always just file content, not the default application locale. Is it possible for users to configure their Windows machine to use UTF-16 as the system codepage without breaking at least half the applications?

As far as I can tell, all the pre-Unicode muti-byte encodings use in Asia still map the ASCII range 00-7F to something which is compatible to ASCII at least for the letters and digits. Is there any Asian encoding still in use which uses more than a single byte for *all* its codepoints? Or perhaps on some other continent?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple program allowing to find out. It's up to you to decide if the failing charsets are common enough or not.

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class EncodingTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        byte[] b = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        for (Charset cs : Charset.availableCharsets().values()) {
            try {
                byte[] b2 = s.getBytes(cs);
                if (!Arrays.equals(b, b2)) {
                    System.out.println(cs.displayName() + " doesn't give the same result");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(cs.displayName() + " throws an exception");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result on my machine is

```
IBM-Thai doesn't give the same result
IBM01140 doesn't give the same result
IBM01141 doesn't give the same result
IBM01142 doesn't give the same result
IBM01143 doesn't give the same result
IBM01144 doesn't give the same result
IBM01145 doesn't give the same result
IBM01146 doesn't give the same result
IBM01147 doesn't give the same result
IBM01148 doesn't give the same result
IBM01149 doesn't give the same result
IBM037 doesn't give the same result
IBM1026 doesn't give the same result
IBM1047 doesn't give the same result
IBM273 doesn't give the same result
IBM277 doesn't give the same result
IBM278 doesn't give the same result
IBM280 doesn't give the same result
IBM284 doesn't give the same result
IBM285 doesn't give the same result
IBM290 doesn't give the same result
IBM297 doesn't give the same result
IBM420 doesn't give the same result
IBM424 doesn't give the same result
IBM500 doesn't give the same result
IBM870 doesn't give the same result
IBM871 doesn't give the same result
IBM918 doesn't give the same result
ISO-2022-CN throws an exception
JIS_X0212-1990 doesn't give the same result
UTF-16 doesn't give the same result
UTF-16BE doesn't give the same result
UTF-16LE doesn't give the same result
UTF-32 doesn't give the same result
UTF-32BE doesn't give the same result
UTF-32LE doesn't give the same result
x-IBM1025 doesn't give the same result
x-IBM1097 doesn't give the same result
x-IBM1112 doesn't give the same result
x-IBM1122 doesn't give the same result
x-IBM1123 doesn't give the same result
x-IBM1364 doesn't give the same result
x-IBM300 doesn't give the same result
x-IBM833 doesn't give the same result
x-IBM834 doesn't give the same result
x-IBM875 doesn't give the same result
x-IBM930 doesn't give the same result
x-IBM933 doesn't give the same result
x-IBM935 doesn't give the same result
x-IBM937 doesn't give the same result
x-IBM939 doesn't give the same result
x-JIS0208 doesn't give the same result
x-JISAutoDetect throws an exception
x-MacDingbat doesn't give the same result
x-MacSymbol doesn't give the same result
x-UTF-16LE-BOM doesn't give the same result
X-UTF-32BE-BOM doesn't give the same result
X-UTF-32LE-BOM doesn't give the same result
```

Comment: Thanks for the listing. Unfortunately I've got trouble deciding how commonly those character sets are being used as application default charsets. I haven't found any codepage prevalence statistics or similar yet. The IBM pages sound like DOS or mainframe. JIS X 0212 apparently was/is mostly used inside EUC-JP which is ASCII-compatible. ISO-2022-CN can only used for decoding.